# How to move spatial data from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, gis, postgis, oracle-spatial

Does anyone have a clear document on how to move Oracle Spatial data to Postgres (both Community version and Enterprise DB... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First, on Postgres you will need to install [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/).  Then export your Oracle tables either to Shapefile (try [SD02SHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdo2shp/) described [here](http://www.mercatorgeosystems.com/docs/sdo2shp/readme.txt))  or [to KML](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/lokitz-spatial-geoserver.html).  If you can export them to shapefile, reimport them to PostGIS with `shp2pgsql` per [these instructions](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html#id2537558).  If you use kml, reimport the geometry with the geometry constructor [ST_GeomFromKML](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_GeomFromKML.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ogr2ogr. To connect to Oracle you need the OCI.dll provided by the Advanced Install of OSGeo4W.

```
ogr2ogr -a_srs *srs* -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" -nln *postgis schema*.*postgis table* PG:"host=*postgis host* user=*postgis user* password=*postgis password* dbname=*postgis database*" OCI:"*oracle user*/*oracle password*@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *hostname*)(PORT = *port number*)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID =*sid name*))):*oracle schema*.*oracle table*"
```

srs = in the EPSG format e.g EPSG:27700

See these other links:

[Migrate SPATIAL data from Oracle to Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789686/migrate-spatial-data-from-oracle-to-postgresql)

http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/foss-gis-suite/2009-August/000781.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also probably export the geometries from Oracle as Well Known Text and then reimport them. This would require you writing import statements for the tables which should be pretty easy to create